# Scroll to bottom of an overflowing div in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a `ul` with a `max-height` and `overflow-y: auto`.

When the user enters enough `li` elements, the `ul` starts to scroll, but I want the last `li` with the `form` in it to always be present and viewable to the user.

I've tried implementing a `scrollToBottom` function that looks like this:

```
scrollToBottom() {
    this.formLi.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}
```

But that just makes the `ul` jump to the top of the screen and show the `li` with the form in it as the only visible thing.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Answers I find tend to be a bit older and use ReactDOM. Thanks!

CSS:

```css
.prompt-box .options-holder {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 12px auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul className='options-holder'>
    {
        this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id} className={`option ${index === 0 ? 'first' : ''}`}>
                <div className='circle' onClick={this.removeItem} />

                <p className='item-text'>{ item.text }</p>
            </li>
        ))
    }

    <li key={0} className={`option form ${this.state.items.length === 0 ? 'only' : ''}`} ref={el => (this.formLi = el)}>
        <div className='circle form' />

        <form className='new-item-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                autoFocus 
                className='new-item-input' 
                placeholder='Type something and press return...' 
                onChange={this.handleChange} 
                value={this.state.text}
                ref={(input) => (this.formInput = input)} />
        </form>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: In this case, maybe you move the last li out of ul, and add another wrapper

Comment: Why would I want to do that rather than just scroll the ul?

Answer (score 57):

I have a container that fills the height of the page. This container has display flex and flex direction column. Then I have a `Messages` component which is a `ul`  with one `li` per message plus a special `AlwaysScrollToBottom` component as the last child that, with the help of `useEffect`, scrolls to the bottom of the list.

```
const AlwaysScrollToBottom = () => {
  const elementRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => elementRef.current.scrollIntoView());
  return <div ref={elementRef} />;
};

const Messages = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map(({id, text}) => <li key={id}>{text}</li>)}
    <AlwaysScrollToBottom />
  </ul>
)

const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <Messages items={[...]}>
    <MessageComposer />
  </div>
)
```

The CSS is

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

`MessageComposer` has been omitted for brevity, it contains the form, the input field, etc. to send messages.

Comment: This is gorgeous and works perfectly even with weird `position: fixed` layouts and things covering it. Thank you!

Comment: This is an elegant and nice solution.

Comment: Amazing solution. I wasn't expecting that works so great! Thanks.

Comment: While this answer is great, it didn't quite work for me because I was using grid, not flexbox. I refactored this idea to a custom Hook here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74719170/4111862.

Answer (score 13):

Use [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) library. However you will have to explicitly set ID of your `ul`.

```
import { animateScroll } from "react-scroll";

scrollToBottom() {
    animateScroll.scrollToBottom({
      containerId: "options-holder"
    });
}
```

You can call `scrollToBottom` on setState callback.

For example

```
this.setState({ items: newItems}, this.scrollToBottom);
```

Or by using setTimeout.

Or you can even set `Element` from `react-scroll` and scroll to a certain `li`.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue when it came to rendering an array of components that came from a user import. I ended up using the componentDidUpdate() function to get mine to work.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        // I was not using an li but may work to keep your div scrolled to the bottom as li's are getting pushed to the div
        const objDiv = document.getElementById('div');
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
      }
```

Comment: this worked for me in React

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you're building a chat-like interface. You can try wrapping the `<ul>` and the `div.circle-form` in a separate div like below:

```css
ul{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:13em;
  overflow-y:auto;
  position:relative;
}
ul li{
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:0;
  padding:6px;
}

.wrapper{
  background:#eee;
  height:15em;
  position:relative;
}
.circle-form{
  background:#ddd;
  height:2em;
  padding:3px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:2;
}
.circle-form input[type=text]{
  padding:8px;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <ul id="list">
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="circle-form">
        <input type="text" name="type_here" placeholder="Enter something..." autofocus/>
    </div>
</div>
```

***EDIT***

And to scroll to the bottom of the list with javascript

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.scrollTop = list.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: I'm not using jquery in my app and don't intend to

Comment: Edited from jquery to vanilla javascript

Comment: can you do this with refs?

Comment: @zero_cool Check my answer below that uses refs https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266099/1128216

Answer (score 1):

I have a script that I've used in one of my projects to scroll top Smoothly, I made a little refactor to scroll the height of your div (scroll bottom) I hope it helps.

***scroll.js***

```
function currentYPosition() {
  if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
  if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollHeight) return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  if (document.body.scrollHeight) return document.body.scrollHeight;

  return 0;
}

function elmYPosition(eID) {
  let elm = document.getElementById(eID);
  let y = elm.offsetHeight;
  let node = elm;
  while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
    node = node.offsetParent;
    y += node.offsetHeight;
  }
  return y;
}

export default function smoothScroll(eID, string) {
  let startY = currentYPosition();
  let stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
  let distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
  let speed = Math.round(distance / 10);
  let speedTimeout = 250;
  if (speed >= 100) speed = 100;
  if (string) speed = 1;
  let step = Math.round(distance / 25);
  let leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
  let timer = 0;
  if (stopY > startY) {
    for (let i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
      setTimeout('window.scrollTo(0, ' + leapY + ')', timer * speed);
      leapY += step;
      if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY;
      timer++;
    }
    return;
  }
  for (let i = startY; i > stopY; i -= step) {
    setTimeout('window.scrollTo(0, ' + (leapY) + ')', timer * speed);
    leapY -= step;
    if (leapY < stopY){
      leapY = stopY;
    } 
    timer++;
  }
}
```

You should import this inside your component, there are 2 parameters(the ID of your element, in this case, you can use ref. The second one is a string that I've used to treat the speed of the scrolling.

```
import scroll from './your-path/scroll.js';
.
.
.
<ul className='options-holder'>
{
    this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={item.id} className={`option ${index === 0 ? 'first' : ''}`} ref={el => (this.formLi = el)}>
            <div className='circle' onClick={this.removeItem} />

            <p className='item-text'>{ item.text }</p>
        </li>
    ))
}

<li key={0} className={`option form ${this.state.items.length === 0 ? 'only' : ''}`} ref={el => (this.formLi = el)}>
    <div className='circle form' />

    <form className='new-item-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input 
            autoFocus 
            className='new-item-input' 
            placeholder='Type something and press return...' 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
            value={this.state.text}
            ref={(input) => (this.formInput = input)} />
    </form>
</li>
```

Idk how you are mapping this LI inside your render but you should make a verification and if there's the property Overflow you should run the scroll.

There's a reasonable answer for your component is jumping to the first element, you're hitting the ref for the FIRST element, not the last.

**Possible workaround:**

```
scroll(this.state.items[this.state.items.length - 1]);
```

**Update 1:** Gist of the original scroll.js, [scrolling to the top](https://gist.github.com/yuripramos/50b9f27b79f47f3970eea7a7af08de4d)

Comment: Thanks Yuri. To be clear, only the `li` with the `form` inside of it has the `ref` tag on it. Not the other ones. The possible workaround isn't working as the `ref` nor `this` have a `scroll` function

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `position:sticky` s.t. the last list item is always shown.

```
li:last-child {
  position:sticky;
  bottom:0;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/fjwwrm9d/)

[Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky)

Comment: I think they wanted the chat to automatically scroll to show the lowest <li> element, but to have normal scroll behaviour for the whole list otherwise. This is a neat css feature though!

Answer (score 0):

i solved it with a general utility function that works outside of any specific component. you need to define a ref on the parent (list box, multiline edit, whatever) and the last child element (or wherever you wish to scroll to).

```
export const scrollToRef = (parentRef, childRef) => {
    trace("scrollToRef:ref.current.offsetTop", childRef.current.offsetTop);
    parentRef.current.scrollTo(0, childRef.current.offsetTop)
}
```

Im using it a functional component and calling it as an effect whenever my parent container gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266099/4111862) didn't quite work for me because I am using CSS Grid instead of Flexbox so the added `div` created another grid row.

To work around this I elaborated to create a Hook which takes a `ref` and gets the last child to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const useScrollToBottom = ref => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ref?.current?.querySelector(':scope > :last-child')?.scrollIntoView()
  }, [ref])
}
```

```js
const Messages = ({ items }) => {
  const scrollContainer = useRef()
  useScrollToBottom(scrollContainer)

  return (
    <ul ref={scrollContainer}>
      {items.map(({id, text}) => <li key={id}>{text}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will help you scroll through the contents of a `div` named `myDiv` and end up changing a state called `isScrolled`

Here We've Typescript Code

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface MyComponentProps {
   isScrolled: boolean;
}

const MyComponent = ({ isScrolled }: MyComponentProps) => {
   const myDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (isScrolled) {
         const myDiv = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(myDivRef.current);
            if (myDiv instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
               myDiv.scroll({
                  top: myDiv.scrollHeight,
                  behavior: 'smooth'
               });
         }
      }
   }, [isScrolled])

   return <div ref={myDivRef}>Div Content</div>;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use "react-scroll-to-bottom" module to do it.

Auto scroll to bottom when new child added.

```
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom';

<ScrollToBottom className={ROOT_CSS}>
   <p>
       Nostrud nisi duis veniam ex esse laboris consectetur officia et. Velit 
       cillum est veniam culpa magna sit
  </p>
</ScrollToBottom>
```

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-bottom