# How to scroll an element into center of window when it's the "last element" on the page

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of `div` elements that contain text and inputs. The first `div` is always visible. Whenever a `div`'s input changes, next `div` becomes visible. I want to automatically scroll down the window as these new divs become visible, preferably having the last visible `div` in the vertical-center of the screen.

`element.scrollIntoView({block: 'center'})` generally works, but it makes the top of the last visible `div` at the bottom of the window, so the user is forced to scroll further to see the inputs inside the `div`. I want the last `div`'s top to be in the center of the window and have empty space underneath the div until the next div is revealed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I was able to solve my issue with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719909/scroll-to-bottom-of-an-overflowing-div-in-react/45837342 using the solution from Jonathan Morales Vélez.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Window.scrollTo()` method to place the top of a `div` in the center of the viewport.

This example will scroll to the fourth div:

```js
// scroll to the fourth div when button is clicked

const divFour = document.getElementById('fourth');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.onclick = function() {

  // get height of the window
  const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  
  // get position in the document of the div's top
  const elTop = divFour.offsetTop;
  
  // scroll window to locate top of div at middle of window
  window.scrollTo(0, elTop - (viewportHeight / 2));
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#fourth {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  color: white;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 6px;
  right: 60px;
  z-index: 1024;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button>Scroll to fourth div</button>

  <div>first div</div>
  <div>second div</div>
  <div>third div</div>
  <div id="fourth">fourth div</div>
  <div>fifth div</div>
  <div>sixth div</div>
</body>
```